# 'TFGPT2LMHeadModel' object has no attribute 'device'?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, nlp, conv-neural-network, nlp-question-answering

I added two models to my project where model 'TFGPT2LMHeadModel' has the error of not finding the device attribute in this model. One of my functions named generate_desc takes attributes like a model, tokenizer, photo, and max_length where I used the keyword 'model_device' in this function that shows the error.I provide code for this problem:

```py
def generate_desc(model, tokenizer, photo, max_length):
    in_text = 'start'
    for i in range(max_length):
        input_ids = tokenizer.encode(in_text, return_tensors="pt")  # Use encode method
        input_ids = input_ids.to(model.device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(input_ids, inputs_embeds=photo)
            logits = outputs.logits
        predicted_token_id = torch.argmax(logits[:, -1, :]).item()
        predicted_word = tokenizer.decode(predicted_token_id)
```

```py
AttributeError:'TFGPT2LMHeadModel' object has no attribute 'device'`"
```

I want to fix my error whatever else it is. Just Fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `device` not `model.device`

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
input_ids = input_ids.to(device)
```